# Do not fail test case if Driver initialization in beforeclass annotation fails

Tags: java, selenium, testng, appium

I have a situation where I wish not to fail my test case if driver initialization fails in beforeclass annotation. I am using appium driver setup in beforeclass and if appium driver fails to recognize connected devices or cannot instantiate the driver itself, my test case is failing. Instead of failing the test when beforeclass fails Is there a workaround ? if yes what are the alternatives?

(Basically I am running the test cases from Jenkins and if jenkins build fails we are triggering alerts to support teams)

Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 2):

You can catch the exception in the BeforeClass method and throw a SkipException for testng to skip all the tests.  This would mark the testcases as **skipped** and not as **failed**.

eg.

```
@BeforeClass
public void bc(){
try{
   //init driver
}catch(WebdriverInitException e){
  throw new SkipException("Problem initializing driver "...trace);
}
}
```